# PHP: Using array_chunk with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I cant get this to work, is it possible? I need to display an banner ad after every 25 wallpapers...

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("wallpaper.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 
foreach (array_chunk($xml->children, 25, true) as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $wall)
    { 
        echo "<a href='" . $wall->url . "' target='_blank'><img src='"$wall->thumbnail . "' alt='Wallpaper' /></a> \n";
    }
    echo '<div id="banner">Test</div>';} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

When I write things like this I use the $i = 0 thing. Then I use the $i = count++ after each foreach. Then I do the if $i = 25 { echo 'img banner code' }.

This above (unfinished) code counts the number of foreach iterations, and when it has reached 25 it echoes your banner images.

Is the code you want? If so I might finish it for you.

Comment: Can you please fix the code? What I need is a loop (25 wallpaper, Banner, 25 wallpaper, Banner, etc...)